# multidimensional js arrays to sql

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, database, postgresql

I have many arrays of numbers in JS files that are multidimensional and I want to get the groups opinion of the best way to convert, store and access them from a mysql database using ajax on the fly. Currently I load the arrays in a js file and read with JS but when it comes time to update prices it can be a nightmare so I want to create them as database tables.

Below is a sample of a longer array the first value of each array is my size and each comma separated value after it is the price based on users selection for another product parameter.

I have been looking at storing in mysql JSON data type and or using a postgre database perhaps?

```
var dArr =[];
dArr[0] =[1,3.2,3.2,3.9,5.1,0,0,0,0];
dArr[1] =[2,3.9,3.9,4.6,6.7,8.2,11.4,15.8,28.4];
dArr[2] =[3,4.2,4.2,5.3,9.2,9.3,13.1,18.5,33.3];
dArr[3] =[4,4.5,4.5,6.3,9.9,11.2,15.6,21.8,39.4];
dArr[4] =[5,5,5,6.7,10,12.1,16.9,23.6,42.4];
dArr[5] =[6,5.5,5.5,7.6,11.8,14.2,19.8,27.7,49.9];
dArr[6] =[7,6.5,6.5,9.2,13.5,16.4,23,32.2,58];
dArr[7] =[8,7.5,7.5,11.1,16,19.4,27,37.8,68.2];
```

Comment: Why not just declare this in one shot as `var dArr = [ [ 1,3.2, ... ], [2, 3.9, ...] ... ]`? The way you've done it here is highly error-prone. Whatever you have you can store in JSON, it's just plain data here, though the storage method depends entirely on your use cases.

Comment: I recommend using json as well. If you do decide on using postgres. Be sure to use jsonb. You can create an indexes on jsonb to make things faster, and if you store it as json you'll see some weird things like duplicate keys, or extra whitespace. Plus postgres has a lot of support for the json data type.